# Microservices and bounded context - how to handle popular service in the system?

Tags: microservices

I'm writing a new microservice app. event driven app.
The app handles crypto currency wallets.

There is a service: "Coin Service", this one holds data that every other service need access to.

I have 10 services, 9 out of 10 services needs to have access to coin service data.
I dont want to sync all of its data 9 times to the other services...
On the other hand, I dont want to allow access via api to other service. it would become a monolith if i open the data to an api...

How can such thing be handled?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you're forcing microservices onto a system which isn't suitable for them.

Comment: @PhilipKendall All the other services are pretty decoupled.

Comment: decoupling only really matters at a system level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the other services *need* access or do they just need a pointer id to a thing in the coin service? If every service just needs a reference to `walletID` that's perfectly fine, no need to replicate data all over the place.

If you really do need data then you need to redesign your services, because you don't have a useful abstraction. You came up with 10 services, maybe you really only need 5. If a microservice can't do something that is valuable from a business perspective without interacting with other services, it's a good sign you are going too micro. If every service needs to talk to a single other service, it could be sign your domains aren't properly thought out or are too thin.

Comment: Thank you. In some of the cases, the need is for data to render the UI. so for example I want to break down wallet most popular coins broken by coin category. Is it ok to implement it in the api gateway? so in the API: Ask for data from the wallet service, Ask for data from coin service and do the calculation?

Comment: yes you can have a gateway endpoint that in reality calls 3 different services and stitches their outputs together. It can be tempting to start putting business logic in the gateway, and that is a problem.